# Floating WinJS.UI.ListView elements in Windows 8 - HTML app

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-8

I am learning windows 8/HTML/JavaScript app creation.
I am trying to create a [WinJS.UI.ListView object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211837.aspx) as described in the MSDN site.

Now I have three listview elements and I want them to be placed on a single row.
I tried used css `float:left` property to display them in one line.

But the problem is I cant get them in a single line.
This is my screenshot of the output
[image]

HTML:

```
 <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        <div id="iconTextApplicationsTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div class="iconTextApplications" >
                <img  class="iconTextApplicationsImage" src="#" data-win-bind="alt: title; src: picture" />
                <div class="iconTextApplicationsTitle" data-win-bind="innerText: title"></div>
            </div>       
        </div>

<div id="iconTextApplications" class="win-selectionstylefilled" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ itemDataSource : Icons.itemList.dataSource, 
    itemTemplate: select('#iconTextApplicationsTemplate'), 
    layout: { type:WinJS.UI.CellSpanningLayout } }" >
```

CSS

```
.win-container{
    margin:auto;
}  
.win-surface {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.win-viewport {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:rgb(94, 82, 68);
}

#iconTextApplicationsTemplate {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var dataArray = [
     { title: "One", picture: "images/jokes.png" },
    {title : "Two" , picture : "images/quotes.png" },
    { title: "Three", picture: "images/trivia.png" }
    ];

var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataArray);
var publicMembers = {
    itemList: dataList
};
WinJS.Namespace.define("Icons",publicMembers);
```

Am I approaching it in the wrong way?

or Should I go for other techniques?

Comment: You can use display:inline-block.

This property allows a DOM element to have all the attributes of a block element, but keeping it inline.

Comment: I tried display:inline-block not working.

Comment: mm have you tried with display:table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinJS you'll need to define the height as the ListView will automagically wrap if the height is either set to auto or 100%.